# Why can't I dynamic_cast this object?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, incomplete-type

```
void test() 
{   
    Token test();   
    Actor* check;   
    check = dynamic_cast<Actor*>(test); 
}
```

This method gives me the following error and underlines the test in the braces with red. The operand of a pointer dynamic_cast must be a pointer to a complete class type

How do i fix this? By the way Actor inherits from Token. Here's the code from Tokens header file.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class Token
{
public:
    Token();
    Token(int x, int y);
    bool IsDead();
    ~Token();
    char Symbol();
    int X, Y;
    bool clear;
    bool indestructable;
    int health;
    int damage, rangeDamage;
    //bool npc;
    char character;
    std::string ToString();
    std::string name;
    bool turnCompleted;
    void SetProfile(char Name);
};
```

Comment: In your code, `test` is a function. It looks like you want it to be a `Token*`.

Comment: why are trying to cast the token function into actor pointer?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you are not creating instance of class `Token` called `test` but rather declare a function `test()` that returns `Token`.

Second you can try to convert pointer to `Token`, not object instance, so you should take address:

```
void test()
{
     Token test;
     Actor* check = dynamic_cast<Actor*>(&test);
}
```

Third, you say that `Actor` inherits from `Token`, but `Token` does not have any virtual functions, so you cannot use `dynamic_cast` on it. A good candidate in your case is `Token`'s destructor.